# Issues upgrading a c3 instance to a c5

Tags: amazon-web-services

This week I'm working on some cost-saving tasks and I'm moving up some instances from the c3 family (c3.8xlarge) to the c5 family (c5.4xlarge).

I'm facing some issues at the boot time of the c5 family, this is what Cloudwatch shows:

[image: CPU graph]

And the same with the network out bytes:

[image: network out bytes]

The rest of the dashboards show the same behaviour, a huge spike at the boot time and then zero.

---

From the SSH perspective, the instance is totally unresponsive.
This is what I have tried so far:

- Use the `Launch more like this` feature to get an instance to test.
- Moved up Ubuntu generic Kernel to `4.4.0-1067.77`
- Moved the Ubuntu AWS Kernel to `4.4.0-1085-aws`
- Followed [these AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/boot-error-linux-m5-c5/) to check if the instance is compatible with a c5, no errors so far.

---

I have tried with some instances from the c4 family (c4.4xlarge) and didn't face any issue. This seems to be related with the Nitro kernel that the c5 family has.

**Could you please point me to any other thing I could try here?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does anything on your instance depend on device names or device mappings? They changed for the "5" series of instances. I also remember that I had to apply some kind of piece of software to my Amazon Linux server when I moved from t2 to t3a, I forget what it is, but perhaps some kind of a driver? Not sure it's that though. You could try launching the base AMI without your customisations then adding your software / tools / configurations one by one. If you have AWS support they'd probably have this worked out for you pretty quickly.

Comment: The current running instance that I have it just has the root volume and 4TiB EBS volume linked that is creating several LVM virtual volumes.

But in the testing instance I'm using I only have the root volume, so I would guess I'm not impacted by anything of that.

Regarding the part of the changes I used the AWS script that checks if the ENA is enabled (which it does after installing the latest available Ubuntu kernel) or moving to the linux-aws kernel.
Thanks for the answer!